# how to run libhydro.dll file from c++ using gcc

Tags: c++, gcc

I have a dll file [libhydro](https://www.crwr.utexas.edu/gis/gishydro03/LibHydro/LibHydro.htm)

I tried to call that from a cpp file

```
#include<iostream>
#include<libhydro>
using namespace std;
int main(void){

return 0;
}
```

i am getting error as

```
test.cpp:3:19: 
fatal error: libhydro: No such file or directory
 #include<libhydro>
                   ^
compilation terminated.
```

Comment: A library typically comes with *header files*, a *linker library* and then the DLL. You include the header files, link with the linker library, and the OS will load your DLL. If your case it seems that the library is not actually a C++ library, but a Visual Basic 6 library, so there's no simple way to use it from C++.

Comment: .There it is written as:-A Dynamic Link Library, or DLL, file is a library of functions or subroutines that can be called from a executable file (.exe).  A DLL can be called by a program written in FORTRAN, C, C++, Visual Basic, or any other COM-compliant language.  For example, a DLL file written in FORTRAN can be called from an EXCEL macro to perform a hydrologic calculation.  Likewise, ArcMap, ArcCatalog, or Access can also call functions or subroutines stored in a DLL file.

Comment: how to call subroutines in dll using c++

Comment: First of all you need to know the ***exact*** function names of the functions you want to call in the DLL, and their arguments and argument types. Then you need to learn about the [`LoadLibrary`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684175%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and [`GetProcAddress`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683212%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and [related functions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682599%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). Since it's a DLL targeted for VB6 I don't even know if it's possible.